# How to make Button on LWC card look like native UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, ui, lightning-base-component

I have a **LWC** component that (tries) to visually mimic the native Task List using `lightning-card` and `lightning-button-menu` but the New Button just looks different regarding the padding and size of the icon.

[image]

Here is how my HTML (no css) looks like:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h2 slot="title" class="bold-title">...</h2>

        <lightning-button-menu slot="actions" icon-name="utility:new" icon-size="x-small" menu-alignment="right" variant="border-filled">
            <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
                <lightning-menu-item key={option.id} value={option.id} label={option.label}></lightning-menu-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-button-menu>
```

Comment: Are you in Winter 20? That has been doing some odd stuff to my CSS in the native app as well, so wondering if they are related?

Comment: No I am still on Summer '19

Comment: @RobertSösemann: In this code ( HTML ) the attribute icon-size for lightning-button-menu is provided as "x-small" , could you try - medium or large & see if it works ?

Comment: @StormBr34ker doesn’t work 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base component is using the proper CSS and matches the SLDS blueprint: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/button-icons/#With-a-Dropdown The issue is that the button menu that you are calling "native" is actually NOT using the correct SLDS styling. I will file a bug on the team to fix.

Comment: So what should I do now? Wait until the native component look as ugly as my base component?;-) or is there a chance to make it look  as good as the native one.